# How to run ffmpeg on demand when someone opens my website with the player where a remote IP camera is displayed?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, stream, rtsp, ip-camera

I set up an nginx server to stream from an IP camera located elsewhere, I used a windows server because it was the one I had no use for (I usually prefer linux), I would need to know how I can make the ffmpeg command run only when someone opens the website where the player is located.

This is my nginx.conf server code:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
        application live {
            live on;
            on_publish http://*******:8080/auth;
            dash on; 
            dash_path tmp/dash;
            
            
        }
    }
}
http{

   server {
        listen 8080;
        location /auth {
        if ($arg_psk = '*****') {
    return 201;
    }
  return 404;
  }
}
   
   server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name stream.*****.com;
        
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate C:/Certbot/live/stream.*****.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key C:/Certbot/live/stream.****.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        charset utf-8;
        location /dash {
            root tmp;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        }
        location / {
            root www;
        }
        

   }
}
```

The command that I use from the DOS console in windows is this:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://*****:******@******.com:557/Streaming/Channels/101 -c copy -f flv -y -t 35 rtmp://********:1935/live/stream?psk=********
```

Basically what I need is that ffmpeg is not running constantly, only when someone wants to view the video from the IP camera. (I have programmed ffmpeg to finish after 35 seconds, although I will put five minutes later)